# error : Cannot find table 0

Tags: asp.net

```
 con.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblbooking where bookid =(select max(bookid) from tblbooking)", con);
 DataSet ds4 = new DataSet();
 pay = ds4.Tables[0].Rows[0]["costoftickets"].ToString();
 Label4.Text = "Amount to Pay : " + pay + " INR.";
 da4.Fill(ds4);
 DetailsView1.DataSource = ds4;
 DetailsView1.DataBind();
 con.Close();
```

Comment: Can you debug  ds4.Tables[0].Rows.Count ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not filled the DataSet before accessing its contents, so naturally there's no data in it.

```
con.Open(); 
SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblbooking where bookid =(select max(bookid) from tblbooking)", con); 
DataSet ds4 = new DataSet(); 
da4.Fill(ds4); // this needs to go before accessing the data
pay = ds4.Tables[0].Rows[0]["costoftickets"].ToString(); 
Label4.Text = "Amount to Pay : " + pay + " INR."; 
DetailsView1.DataSource = ds4; 
DetailsView1.DataBind(); 
con.Close();
```

Note that you still might get errors if your query returns no data.

Comment: sorry for that but table have 7 rows. properly inserted